# how to change the size of the image retrived from the oracle db

Tags: oracle, blob

Hi:
In our oracle db,there is a blob column used to save the images.

Now I have to display them in the web page,so I create a Image.aspx,which will read the binary blob data and write them to the response so I can insert this image using :

```
<img src="Image.aspx?id=xx />
```

However the size(16k,12M?) and the resoution(800x600,4000x1299?) is not sure,so somethime the image may so large,it will cost much time to download,also some images's resolution is more than 2000x2000,so I want to zoom in them to a small scale.

That's to say I have read the image binary and chagne them to a "Image" object,read its size and change it?

How to make it?

Comment: Would this be more appropriately tagged as .Net? I'm pretty sure this could be done by the db but might be easier on the app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution is to have three columns in your image table which contain the width, the height and a thumbnail in a reasonable resolution (say scaled to ratio in a 256x256 or 512x512 rectangle).

That way, you can figure out how big the image will be without the expensive loading and the thumbnail should work in most situations.

Comment: I can not change the data structure of the db.

Comment: Then you can't solve your problem. You can't scale the image without loading the whole blob. Some image loaders allow you to load just the header to find out the size and depth of the image but to zoom, you need the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function for resizing a blob image field:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resize_img (i_ID INTEGER)
   RETURN BLOB
IS
   vImageData     BLOB;
   vSizedImage BLOB;

BEGIN

SELECT img_simbolo_op
         INTO vImageData
         FROM tbl_yourtable
        WHERE my_ID = i_ID; 

  DBMS_Lob.createTemporary(vSizedImage, FALSE, DBMS_LOB.CALL);

   ORDSYS.OrdImage.processCopy(vImageData, 'maxScale=75 75', vSizedImage);


   return vSizedImage;

END resize_img;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle [built-ins](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14297/ch_imgref.htm#sthref791) to rescale/size the image
But you'd have to use the BLOB in a constructor for an ORDImage. Then [get the Ordimage properties](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14297/ch_imgref.htm#sthref666) which might be a bit of a strain.